# Conversion by a Rabbi who is not in the list of Israeli Supreme Court

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

If one underwent Judaism conversion and hold a conversion certificate with 3 Beit Din signature, the conversion is performed by an Orthodox Rabbi ,  but the Rabbi is not in the list of Israeli Supreme Court, is that person a Jew?
If gentiles are not allowed to observe Shabbat, should the person keep Shabbat?

Comment: If they converted properly why wouldn't they be Jewish? Being Jewish and convincing others you are Jewish are two separate things.

Comment: The Baga"tz (Israeli Supreme Court) and Rabbanut are two separate organisations. The former's definition is significantly more lenient than the latter's. The Rabbanut only accepts some Orthodox batei din outside of Israel, whereas the Baga"tz accepts Conservative/Masorti and Reform/Liberal conversions as Jewish.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt, I think he means the Beit Din HaGadol HaRabbani list

Answer (score 5):

Yes that a person is jewish. The state of Israel has no halachik authority in determining who is a jew. If one converts with a valid orthodox conversion and bet din then one is a jew, even if the israeli rabbinate does not think so.

Comment: I mean no offense, but no one here knows you to trust your say-so. Can you source your claim?